# How to insert several new elements into another element with XSL, keeping everything else unchanged

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf

I have written an XSLT that is supposed to add one or more skos:narrower elements within a parent rdf:Description element. Here is a piece of starting xml:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AAA">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"/>
        <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">AAA</skos:prefLabel>
        <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AA"/>
    </rdf:Description>
```

and I want to add a  element for each narrower element in the xml:

```
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AAA">
      <skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AAAA"/>
      <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"/>
      <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">AAA</skos:prefLabel>
      <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AA"/>   
   </rdf:Description>
```

I need to do this in order to specify both the skos:broader and skos:narrower relationships (the vocabulary tool I'm using only stores skos:broader).

The xsl that I wrote does this. However, though the result is close to what I want, it has a flaw. If the element AAA has a narrower element AAAB in addition to AAAA, I get a **separate** rdf:Description element for this case:

```
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AAA">
      <skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AAAB"/>        
      <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"/>
      <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">AAA</skos:prefLabel>
      <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://schema.xxx.com/ns/vocabulary-structure/AA"/>
   </rdf:Description>
```

What I want is to have both the skos:narrower pointing to AAAA and the one pointing to AAAB to be within the same AAA element, rather than two separate elements.

Here is the (I hope) relevant section of the xslt. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

```
<xsl:template match="rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="apply-skos-narrower">
    <xsl:param name="this-concept-id"/>
    <xsl:param name="narrower-concept-id"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@rdf:about=$this-concept-id">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
                    <skos:narrower>
                        <xsl:attribute name="rdf:resource">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$narrower-concept-id"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </skos:narrower>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>         
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>       
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks for the comments. Below is the complete xslt as requested. I'm sure I've misunderstood something here about how the recursion works, so any guidance will be much appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="1.0"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Store the vocabulary identifier as a variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="vocabulary-id" select = "//rdf:Description[child::rdf:type[@rdf:resource='http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology']]/@rdf:about" />

<!-- Replace the massive collection of namespace declarations provided by EVN with a more sensible minimal set, then call the first processing template. -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rdf:RDF xmlns:opencyc="http://sw.opencyc.org/concept/"
            xmlns:freebase="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/" 
            xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
            xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
            xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
            xmlns:dbpedia="http://dbpedia.org/resource/"
            xmlns:sesame="http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#"
            xmlns:cycAnnot="http://sw.cyc.com/CycAnnotations_v1#" 
            xmlns:ctag="http://commontag.org/ns#"
            xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
            xmlns:cyc="http://sw.cyc.com/concept/" 
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
            <!-- Copy the header and Concept Scheme sections - these are fine -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="process-vocabulary-header"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="process-concept-scheme"/>
            <!-- Now process all of the other concepts -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="process-other-concepts"/>
        </rdf:RDF>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process the vocabulary header information -->
    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="process-vocabulary-header">
        <xsl:if test="rdf:type[@rdf:resource='http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology']">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process the ConceptScheme element -->
    <xsl:template match="rdf:Description" mode="process-concept-scheme">
        <xsl:if test="rdf:type[@rdf:resource='http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme']">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="process-other-concepts">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- When we are in the ConceptScheme element, we can get the concepts that have hasTopConcept elements and set the complementary topConceptOf elements -->
            <xsl:when test="rdf:type[@rdf:resource='http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme']">
                <xsl:for-each select="skos:hasTopConcept">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="apply-top-concepts">
                        <xsl:with-param name="top-concept-id" select="@rdf:resource"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- Finally, find the elements with skos:broader elements and set their complementary skos:narrower elements -->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="skos:broader">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="apply-skos-narrower">
                    <xsl:with-param name="this-concept-id" select="skos:broader/@rdf:resource"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="narrower-concept-id" select="./@rdf:about"></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add the topConceptOf element to the right concepts -->
    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="apply-top-concepts">
        <xsl:param name="top-concept-id"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@rdf:about=$top-concept-id">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <skos:topConceptOf>
                        <xsl:attribute name="rdf:resource">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$vocabulary-id"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </skos:topConceptOf>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add the skos:narrower element to the right concepts -->    
    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF/rdf:Description" mode="apply-skos-narrower">
        <xsl:param name="this-concept-id"/>
        <xsl:param name="narrower-concept-id"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@rdf:about=$this-concept-id">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
                        <skos:narrower>
                            <xsl:attribute name="rdf:resource">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$narrower-concept-id"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </skos:narrower>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>         
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you are getting two `rdf:Description` elements created, instead of one, this suggests your template is being called twice (or maybe another template is also copied the element too), so you probably need to include a bit more of your XSLT, to show how and where the template is being called. Thanks!

Comment: You have `<xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>` and `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>`, so the child elements will be copied both before and after the added `narrower` element.

Comment: It feels to me like you're making this far harder than it needs to be - am I correct in distilling the problem down to adding an inverse triple Y-narrower-X for every X-broader-Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a warning: you shouldn't use plain XML processing tools like XSLT to handle RDF-XML unless there's really no alternative.  There are many many equivalent XML representations of the same underlying RDF graph, you're far better off using a proper RDF tool that understands the graph structure.

That said... I think you can achieve what you want in a radically simpler way using a key that will let you look up `skos:broader` elements by their `rdf:resource`.  Then at the point where you're processing an `rdf:Description` X it's trivial to look up the broader triples with X as object, and create the corresponding "narrower" inverses.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="1.0"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="broaderByObject" match="skos:broader" use="@rdf:resource" />

    <!-- identity template - copy everything as-is except for overrides -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rdf:Description">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('broaderByObject', @rdf:about)">
                <!-- the object of the narrower is the subject from the broader -->
                <skos:narrower rdf:resource="{../@rdf:about}" />
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The same principle works for the top concepts - add a key

```
<xsl:key name="topConByObject" match="skos:hasTopConcept" use="@rdf:resource" />
```

and look up the key to create the inverses

```
<xsl:if test="key('topConByObject', @rdf:about)">
    <skos:topConceptOf rdf:resource="{$vocabulary-id}" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I had thought about using a key, but I couldn't work out how it works. You have clarified it nicely.